# How to compute the mean for utility function?

Tags: utility-theory, insurance

Let $u(x)=x^{2/3}$, $x>0$ be the utility function, $X \sim U(0, 100)$ is loss, wealth $w=\\\$150$.

Calculate $\mathbb{E}(u(w_r))$ if a coinsurance is $80\%$ and gross premium is $\\\$43$.

My attempt is:

$E(u(w_r))=\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{43}(150-43)^{2/3}dt + \int_{43}^{100} (150-0.8t)^{2/3}dt=21.3486$

But answer is $21.103$.

**Question.** How to compute the mean for utility function?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you misinterpreted the protection? Also, utility does not stand in $\\\$$. I'd come up with

$$
\frac{1}{100}\int_0^{100}(150-43-0.2t)^{2/3}\mathrm{d}t=21.103
$$

Comment: I have found the term. I think "coinsurance" is correct.